# Is it possible to render BIM models on mobile devices the same way as on desktop?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to know if it's possible to render BIM models on mobile devices the same way as on desktop. The problem we have is the lack of shadows or edges on the elements, for example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppIf1.png

This is how the model looks on desktop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0ERC.png

This is the same model but on mobile device. Notice how it's almost impossible to distinguish windows and other elements.
I've tried to fix this by executing the code...

```
viewer.impl.setDisplayEdges(true)
```

but it did not help.
Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm checking with our engineering team for insights. Will get you back A.S.A.P. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking with our engineering, we finally managed to make the model edges be displayed on my iPad, see the below snapshot for the final result.

To make this happen, please try to load your model with these two options, `createWireframe: true` and `isAEC: true`, then boom! The looks between desktop and mobile are similar. Here is a code snippet for you, please have a try!

```
const loadOptions = {
  createWireframe: true,
  isAEC: true
};

const onGeometryLoaded = () => {
  viewer.removeEventListener(
    Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
    onGeometryLoaded
  );

  // just in case the edge display mode is off, then we set it back to true
  viewer.setDisplayEdges( true );
};

viewer.addEventListener(
  Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
  onGeometryLoaded
);
viewer.loadModel( svf, loadOptions, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback );
```

The final result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Evgeniy,

did you try to set [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v4/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/#setqualitylevel-usesao-usefxaa)?

It might help with your rendering issues.
Have not tried this myself though.